# Rotation of player in OpenGL using 2 vectors

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I want to rotate a player in my opengl game with a key input and I'm not sure how to implement it. Here is the code:

```
void Player::rotate(Vector newDirection)
{
    m_direction.Normalize(); //current direction
    newDirection.Normalize();

    float angle = acos( m_direction.DotProduct( newDirection ) );
    angle = angle * 180/M_PI; //convert to degrees

    Vector rotAxis = m_direction.CrossProduct(newDirection);
    rotAxis.Normalize();

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, rotAxis.x, rotAxis.y, pos.z);
        glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);      
    glPopMatrix();
    render();
}
```

Basically I want to be able to press a key and the player rotate around for the time pressed. For example, when I press 'a' the player rotates left until I let go of the key.

Comment: Where's the code that calls `rotate`?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what it is exactly that you would like to know, so someone can help you clarify it. Also, ideally you could provide [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: glRotatef has `pos.z` instead of `rotAxis.z`, is this a mistake?

Comment: Also, you pop the matrix before doing the render(), this effectively returns the matrix to what it was before the transformation. `render()` should be before `popMatrix()`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I call the rotate function when a key is pressed.

Comment: @shoosh Yes that is supposed to be pos.z not rotAxis.z.

Comment: @DavidJCC:  What's the issue if you can call `rotate` when a key is pressed or **while** a key is pressed?  Perhaps you need an outer loop that checks for a keypress, rotates, then delays before checking again.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the issue is that nothing actually happens when a key is pressed. I wasn't sure if the way I was approaching it was correct either. Is is correct to have the new direction axis as the parameter of the function?

Comment: Have you tried putting some indication, like outputting text, when a button is pressed and held?  I would start there or write a small separate program to validate the rotation and the amount of delay between the rotations.